# Malloc returning zeroed memory as output

Tags: c

*I am using the below mentioned to simply learn about malloc. As I have heard and studied that malloc allocate an unintialized storage for you. So the output of this program should be a garbage value. But I am getting 0 as the output. Please tell me what is wrong here?*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    int *x =(int*)malloc(100000000*sizeof(int));
    printf("%d",x[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT 0

Comment: Why not? Why do you think something is "wrong" here? All garbage values are born equal. `0` is a perfectly good garbage value, not worse or better than any other garbage value. (And you certainly should not expect this code to behave as a random number generator.) What you "heard and studied" was intended to tell you that you should not *rely* on that values always being zero. That's all.

Comment: There is nothing wrong there. It's just happens that the memory at that address has a 0. Some OS, configured for "high security" may initialize every chunk of memory passed to the user so there is no chance that a user gets a memory block previously used by another, maybe root-level process, and which may contain sensitive data (such as portions of the password file or whatever)

Comment: Let me get this right: You want randomized values and complain that garbage implies all-zero? Simple solution: fill the array with random values.

Comment: On Linux, if the `malloc` results in new pages being allocated to your process, those new pages are filled with zeros by the kernel. If, on the other hand, the `malloc` returns memory that was already allocated to your process and later freed, the memory will contain whatever was in there before. In any case, as everyone has already said, the idea is that you can't depend on any particular values being in memory returned by `malloc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the problem with garbage (as well as with undefined behavior) — it could be *anything*. And among the behaviors that fall under the category of "anything" is looking like it's doing something sensible.

(P.S. you should also test the return value of `malloc`; errors can happen, and it will signify the error by returning a null pointer)

Answer (score 3):

If `malloc` returns a null-pointer, and you dereference this null-pointer, you have *undefined behavior*.

If it *doesn't* return `NULL`, then the contents of the memory is *indeterminate* and using it in any way without initialization is *still* undefined behavior.

But to explain your behavior, ***if*** you get a non-null pointer back, then one of the possible value of the indeterminate values is zero. If you get a null-pointer back, then you might a well might had a crash instead of printing a zero.

Also, some environments might initialize memory to certain values when debugging. Clearing everything (i.e. setting most or everything to zero) is common when running in a debugger

Comment: "using it in any way" - which includes *reading* it.

Comment: If you use a type that doesn't have trap values it isn't ub., then the value is just unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the contents of storage with an indeterminate value. This is undefined behaviour. Anything can happen. Some of the things that can happen is the application crashing, your washing machine starting to wash, or your computer printing the number zero.